# How do I add placeholder text in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I'm working on a report but some data, which will be repeated throughout the document, are not yet ready. Is there any way to put a placeholder of some sort that will automatically adjust **other than** using find and replace?

For example, in my document, I write that the current price of Item X is $100. This will appear several times in the same document. However, I might have to adjust the price later on. I can't use find and replace because Item Y and Item Z also cost $100 and their prices are independent of Item X. Is there a tool that will work for this purpose?

I'm sorry if my explanation is hard to understand, English isn't my first language.

Comment: This seems very close to http://superuser.com/questions/645917/repeating-an-user-input-in-rest-of-the-places-in-microsoft-word-docment/646040#646040

Answer (score 3):

Word has a provision for this, which is commonly used with templates to customize documents.  You can create and use variables that you define and maintain in one place and use in other places.  They are called fields (usually written as {fields} because the curely braces delimit them.  The braces aren't actually characters, they must be created using Ctrl-F9 or Insert Field from the menu (in Word 2007, this is under Insert | Quick Parts).  There is a collection of pre-defined fields and you can create you own.  They can contain text, numbers, calculations, conditional tests, etc., so you can do some very powerful template and document automation with them.

The built-in Word help contains a lot of documentation on how to use this feature.  You also might find [this online tutorial](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm) helpful.