# Global Updates to Fields in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document with different fields to fill in (e.g. name, address etc).  These info will repeat throughout the file and I will use this word file as template for next client.

Is there a way I can create something to populate those empty fields quickly?  Eg: Let's say I just have to type name as "David", all the required "name" fields in my document will be filled in with David and if I type once "address" as 123 ABC Way, all the fields for "address" will be updated accordingly.  I read about the Bookmarks trick...but I want something quicker and more efficient.

Thanks!!

Comment: You use the term "field".  Are you referring to it generically or the actual Word fields feature?  Word lets you create fields that work exactly as you describe.  "Quick and efficient" is largely a function of proficiency.  Once you learn how to do it and use it, it can be done pretty fast.  Check Word's built-in help for fields (if you see {field}, you're in the right place).

Comment: Very similar question to http://superuser.com/questions/645917/repeating-an-user-input-in-rest-of-the-places-in-microsoft-word-docment/646040#646040