# How can I link some text inside a word 2016 document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am preparing a word 2016 document which is to be resused several times. This document contains some month-year date, like e.g. "Nov 2016", which is the same throughout the document, and appears on several places inside the document.

Now, I reuse this document and instead of using "Nov 2016" I now want to use "Feb 2017" in all those places. I can go and search for each occurrance of "Nov 2016" and replace it, but the more convenient way would be to use a 'variable' instead of a fixed text "Nov 2016". I just put in the variable inside the text wherever I need it, and the I replace just the variable content from "Nov 2016" to "Feb 2016", and all occurrances of the date are updated throughout the document.

Is there a way to do this? To use a variable, or something else?

Comment: This is in essence a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/645917/repeating-a-user-input-throughout-a-microsoft-word-docment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom property then you can use it:

- go to file, click properties (top of right column) and select "advanced properties"
- go to custom tab, type its name to name field (e.g. MyDate) and its value in Value field, then press add (here you'll be able to modify it)
- press ok

You can insert it to the document by going to insert - quick parts - field; from categories select "Document information", select "DocProperty" in field names and finally select your property from "property" field

You can refresh all fields to its new value by selecting all document content (CTRL+A), right-clicking on a field and selecting "update"